# Building an array from other arrays

Tags: javascript

I am building an array from other arrays. These other arrays are the returned value from a function. Sometimes the returned value from the function is empty (or maybe null?).

My centralList returns an empty value. Is that because I am not correctly dealing with the empty returned values from the checkPieceInColumnArray function? Is it best practice to never have an empty value returned from a function? What should I be doing?

My code below is used to build the array.

```
centralList = [
    ...checkPieceInColumnArray('P', 'd', currentPosition),
    ...checkPieceInColumnArray('P', 'e', currentPosition),
    ...checkPieceInColumnArray('p', 'd', currentPosition),
    ...checkPieceInColumnArray('p', 'e', currentPosition),
  ];
```

Comment: *"My centralList returns an empty value.*" Do you mean `centralList` is `[]`? That's perfectly valid if all those function calls return `[]`. If `checkPieceInColumnArray` returns `null`, spread will throw an error. Do you have an error?

Comment: You can simplify the repetative calls: `[...'dede'].flatMap(c => checkPieceInColumnArray('P', c, currentPosition) ?? [])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```
centralList = [
    ...(checkPieceInColumnArray('P', 'd', currentPosition) ?? []),
    ...(checkPieceInColumnArray('P', 'e', currentPosition) ?? []),
    ...(checkPieceInColumnArray('p', 'd', currentPosition) ?? []),
    ...(checkPieceInColumnArray('p', 'e', currentPosition) ?? []),
  ];
```

Comment: I don't understand the ?? []. Is that saying if it is an empty array, add nothing?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to debug the output of your function to determine what the output is so you can debug the built list. Example:

```
console.log('FirstValue',checkPieceInColumnArray('P', 'd', currentPosition));
```

If any of these functions returned **null** then you should get an error. If they returned an empty array, there would be no error.  Since javascript is an untyped language you could return **null** from that function but if you want to be able to expect the result to be an array then in most cases it's better to return an empty array. Judging by your question I suspect your function is always returning an empty array.

Comment: Had already used console.log, but now added empty array returned rather than null. Thanks.